# Convert i of For Loop to QString

Tags: c++, qt

Edited-

Here's where I'm getting thrown down:

```
for(int i=0, a=bugModel->rowCount(); i<a; i++){
        qDebug() << i;
        QString *BugName = new QString(QString::number(i));
        setting.beginGroup(BugName->toAscii());
        bugModel->setData(bugModel->index(i,0), setting.value("theBugName",  "A Bug!").toString());
        setting.endGroup();
        delete BugName;
    }
```

I'm trying to load a Name from the setting group and set it to a list model, for which the name will equal to i. But everytime I load the model, the information of the group '0' only shows up, because i is 0 in here. For example:

I have two setting group named '0' and '1'. I want the for loop to run 2 times so that it loads the value from these groups and set it in the QListView. But I tested it out and everytime it loads only the value of the '0' group, and when I change it to `for(int i=1..)` it loads the value of the group '1'.

Comment: And the reason for allocating something as fundamental as a string dynamically just to `delete` it at the end of the scope is? Used to Java, I guess? In that case it at least honors you that you didn't just leave away the `delete`.

Comment: Acually that's the suggestion of soeone who commented in here..i dont  even know java..hehe

Answer (score 1):

To fix the first case, you can `(*BugName) = QString::number(i)` or `BugName->setNum(i);`, but the bigger question is what are you trying to achieve and how do you check if it stays zero? What do you expect to change? Maybe give more context?

Comment: Well I'm trying to set infos to a model and save them based on some complex things. Can you please explain your code? Will help me to understand better.

Comment: Wish *you* could explain yours. The first `(*BugName)=QString::number(i)` creates a `QString` object from number and copies its value to the recently created object in `*BugName`. The second version just sets the already created `*BugName` object to the numeric value of `i`. The question is how do you check if it stays zero, at which point do you check it? If you use it? `Trying to set infos` doesn't really help much without seeing some *relevant* code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the weird use of 'a', I'm guessing that there's a bunch of other code that you didn't post. As it stands now, the loop is equivalent to `for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)`, and thus only iterates through i=0 and i=1. On the first pass, it creates a new QString, assigns the address to the bugname pointer, then attempts (incorrectly) to assign a string to it.  You can change the second line to `*BugName = QString::number(i);` and it should work. Even better, you can use one of the QString constructors and change the first line to `QString* BugName = new QString(QString::number(i))` and eliminate the second line altogether.

Now for the second problem, your memory leak. After the first pass, the loop resets and you create a second qstring, overwritting bugname with the new address.  Unfortunately, this orphans the first qstring you made causing a leak.  Add the line `delete BugName;` just before the end of the loop to fix.  If you're actually trying to create an array of 'BugNames' for use after the loop, you probably want to use an array instead: Put `QString BugNames[2]` before the loop, then use the loop to iterate through and initialize them individually via `BugNames[i] = QString::number[i]`.  Since arrays are automatic variables, you won't need the `delete` part for this latter case.

**Edit**
Looking at your revised code, I would do it this way (old way still valid though):

```
for(int i=0; i < bugModel->rowCount(); i++){
  qDebug() << i;
  QString BugName = QString::number(i);
  setting.beginGroup(BugName.toAscii());
  bugModel->setData(bugModel->index(i,0), setting.value("theBugName",  "A Bug!").toString());
  setting.endGroup();
}
```

Note that your use of 'a' is redundant, since it (and indeed the loop itself) would likely be removed by the compiler. Now that I see what you're doing, I'd ditch the pointer-strings altogether and just go with a single automatic variable.  As for the problem of it not working, qDebug should be outputting "0 1", yes? You can try `qDebug() << BugName;` after the `::number` assignment, but I suspect that will output "0 1" as well.  That would mean that your real issue lies somewhere in the `begin/endGroup()` functions, and not in this loop. If the argument to `beginGroup` gets assigned to something static, you might be overwritting a value with the second pass.

Comment: +1 Although I should say that declaring `QString`s on the heap is generally frowned upon as they use implicit sharing under the hood anyway, so you gain nothing and create another pointer to track.

Comment: Edited my question..check it out